# What is the difference between foo.toString() and Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)?

Tags: javascript

If I define a function:

```
function foo() {
        alert(this.x);
}
```

I can print the function definition by calling the `toString` method on the `foo` function.

```
console.log(foo.toString())
```

output:

> function foo() {
>               alert(this.x);
>       }

If I then run

```
console.log(Object.prototype.toString.call(foo))
```

output:

> "[object Function]"

It is surprising the me that the output is different. I thought these two forms were equivalent?, i.e. the `foo` function inherited the `toString` method from the top level `Object` and using `Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)` was just calling `toString` passing the `foo` function as the `this`.
What is the difference between these two forms of invocation?

Comment: `Object.getPrototypeOf(foo)` vs `Object.getPrototypeOf({})`, the prototype chain of `foo` is `Function.prototype` -> `Object.prototype`, `toString` can be (and is) overridden in `Function.prototype`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the difference between these two forms of invocation?

It's not just a difference in the *form* of the invocation, you're also calling a different function entirely.

> i.e. the `foo` function inherited the `toString` method from the top level `Object` and using `Object.prototype.toString.call(foo)` was just calling `toString` passing the `foo` function as the `this`.

All perfect, except the first bit. :-) `foo` doesn't inherit `toString` from `Object.prototype`, because `foo` is a function, and `Function.prototype` (which inherits from `Object.prototype`) *overrides* `toString` to give it different behavior.

You can see that like this:

```
console.log(foo.toString === Object.prototype.toString); // false
```

It's also entirely possible for `foo` to have its own `toString`, overriding the one it inherits from `Function.prototype`, but by default it doesn't.

So changing just the *form* of the invocation, we'd get these, which are equivalent:

```
console.log(foo.toString());
```

and

```
console.log(foo.toString.call(foo));
```

or if we know `foo` doesn't override `Function.prototype`'s version, then:

```
console.log(Function.prototype.toString.call(foo));
```

Comment: thanks, this clearly explains it. `console.log(foo.toString === Object.prototype.toString); // false` is useful too.

Answer (score 3):

`.toString` is one of the methods that each type of object overrides and customises for its own type. The generic `Object.prototype.toString` method generically prints everything as `[object <type>]`. More specialised sub-types like `Function` or `Array` override that behaviour and format the string into something more appropriate for their type.

Comment: Ah, I wondered if that might have been the case, but I wasn't sure how to query the inheritance chain to find out. I suspect its not possible to print the definitions for the different types because they are internal implementations and you will just get `toString() { [native code] }`?

Comment: @the_velour_fog: Largely, yes. But you can inspect the inheritance chain with `Object.getPrototypeOf(x)` and such.

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent because you are calling two different internal functions.

One is `Object.prototype.toString()` and the other is `Function.prototype.toString()`.

The Object one always prints `"[object [[Class]]]"` (where `[[Class]]` is an ES concept) where the Function object has been defined to return a stringified version of itself (its `toString()` would be reached on the prototype before the one on `Object.prototype`).

Answer (score 0):

Try calling a Function.prototype.toString.call(foo), because Object is a parent for everything, but Function is currently a parent of a foo